# jQuery slider not working in https URL

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a jquery photo slider that is working great in a regular http:// URL like this:

http://tinyurl.com/cswdpbc

My problem starts when I try to access the page with https:// the slider no longer appears.  I have tried to Use the Chrome tools but can't see anything out of the ordinary...can somebody take a peek and let me know what you think it could be?

HTTPS URL: http://tinyurl.com/c29585s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling this: https:  /wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102 and it gives an SSL certificate error, try calling scripts without defining a protocol, like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

also, you could use google's cdn to host that file for you ;)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```