# jQuery slider not working with https URL on a Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a WowSlider that is not working when running the main page of my Wordpress website with https. The images in the slider appear stacked statically one after another. When running the Wordpress website with http, the slider works fine (provides the transition effect expected).

I am trying to figure out how to modify my website such as to launch a javascript with https, not http. I want to launch the javascript as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.allbookcovers.com/skin/frontend/default/hellomini/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> (*)
```

but not as

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.allbookcovers.com/skin/frontend/default/hellomini/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> (**)
```

But since I have not been able to manually edit the source code behind the main page, I have not been able to get (*) to work.

Hence the question: How to modify the Wordpress site (php scripts?) such as to implement (*)?

I have come to understand that the problem has to do with contention between http and https.
My problem resembles the one from
[jQuery slider not working in https URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514853/jquery-slider-not-working-in-https-url)

I believe the same solution will apply. I should launch the javascript using

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

or

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The hypothesis above is supported by an observation from

```
    https://www.allbookcovers.com (***)
```

Here a corresponding WowSlider operates fine with https.

When analyzing the code behind (***), I noticed the following:

```
    <!-- Start wowslider.com Head section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com section -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.allbookcovers.com/skin/frontend/default/hellomini/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.allbookcovers.com/skin/frontend/default/hellomini/js/jquery-magento-fix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.allbookcovers.com/skin/frontend/default/hellomini/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

In my website, the javascript is launched with http, not https:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.allbookcovers.com/skin/frontend/default/hellomini/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to comb through my Wordpress website to figure out where jquery.js was being launched. I found the following in

```
    \\wp-includes\script-loader.php(963):
scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4' ); (****)
```

It was not clear to me how to modify this such as to result in

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.allbookcovers.com/skin/frontend/default/hellomini/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

getting added to the main page, since (****) made no direct reference to http.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any webpage loaded under https will block non-secure ressources. So is your question about *how to bypass* this security level? **Or** how to have a particular ressource loading securely? Please think about that and edit your question. As now, it looks like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me... And can't answer.

Comment: 1. I would like to have the javascript resource load securely. 2. If #1 is not possible, then I would like to bypass this security level. Presently, my website is labeled 'Not Secure' by browsers like the Google Chrome. I believe such a label may deter people from my web site. I am not an expert in Wordpress or Javascripts, but have some years of basic experience of maintaining my site. I am looking to educate myself more, in particular on how to load secure resources. At the end of the day, I want to provide a professional site, one supporting https.

Comment: In your internal urls , replace https:// or http:// with //. <a href="//www.allbookcovers.com/..."

Answer (score -1):

I withdraw the question. I appear to have stumbled on a solution. As I was getting ready to hand-edit the PHP files comprising my website, or even go into the PHP database and manually edit the content, I stumbled on a plugin called "Really Simple SSL". I installed the plugin. And vuha! My problems went away.